# Mocked async method never called in Moq

Tags: c#, async-await, moq, xunit.net

I have a database repository interface:

```
public interface IDbRepository
{
  Task<T> GetDataAsync<T>(Func<T, bool> filter = null) where T : class;
}
```

I have the following fixture:

```
private List<Status> statusList = new List<Status> {
      new Status { Name="Status A"},
      new Status { Name="Status B"}
    };

var repositoryMock = new Mock<IDbRepository>();
Func<Status, bool> filter = It.IsAny<Func<Status, bool>>();
repositoryMock.Setup(repository => repository.GetDataAsync(filter))
  .ReturnsAsync(
  () =>
  {
    //NEVER CALLED
    if (filter == null)
      return statusList.FirstOrDefault();
    return statusList.FirstOrDefault(filter);
  });
```

I use the following test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Repository_GetDataAsync_Filter()
{
  var repository = repositoryTestFixture.Ioc.Resolve<IDbRepository>();
  Func<Status, bool> filter = stat => stat.Name == "Status A";
  var res = await repository.GetDataAsync(filter);
  //await task1.ContinueWith(ctask => Assert.NotNull(ctask.Result));
  Assert.NotNull(res); //ALWAYS NULL!!!
}
```

I tried to debug, and the method never called so I always get a failed test.

According to @Stephen Cleary, the test isn't required [to call](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) `Wait()` or `Result`, and the [old official way](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-2-right-way.html) is deprecated as of Visual Studio 2015, async tests are supported out of the box.

> Stephen Cleary • https://stephencleary.com/ 11 months ago (2017-11-03
>   12:22:06 pm) 
>   As noted in the big red banner at the
>   top of the page, this solution was designed for VS2010. VS2015 works
>   fine with async Task unit tests out of the box.

What should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the `It.IsAny<>()` is inaccurate. It was meant to be used directly in the `Setup` expression only. Not in variables.

When arguments do not match the mock is not invoked. Hence you get null.

Access passed argument within the `ReturnAsync` delegate

```
var repositoryMock = new Mock<IDbRepository>();
repositoryMock
    .Setup(repository => repository.GetDataAsync(It.IsAny<Func<Status, bool>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((Func<Status, bool> filter) => {//<-- grab passed argument here
        if (filter == null)
            return statusList.FirstOrDefault();
        return statusList.FirstOrDefault(filter);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I used it incorrectly, thanks for the clarification. It would be good to provide more complex examples to the official Quickstart document (I maybe provide a PR). Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is due to your `filter` local variable. By creating a variable that is not an expression, you are actually executing the `It.IsAny` call and returning null. As you can imagine, `null` will only match a `null` func, and this is why you don't see the `ReturnsAsync` being hit.

Please try inlining that variable or changing its type to `Expression<Func<Status, bool>>` and see if that works as expected.

You have to always keep in mind that mock setup is done using expressions, so usually the `It.IsX` calls are never executed per se, just analysed and compared as an expression tree.